# Get last month's data

Tags: sql, datetime, sybase

I am trying to get last months data using the following code but keep getting the following error:

> Data exception - argument must be DATE or DATETIME

Here is my code:

```
 SELECT cast(OPEN_DATE as datetime)
 FROM OPENQUERY(serverb,' SELECT cast(OPEN_DATE as datetime)
      FROM xx
       WHERE co_cde = 15   
         and cust_no in (1780066)  
         and cast(OPEN_DATE as datetime)  >=
             DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0)
        AND cast(OPEN_DATE as datetime)   <  
             DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)   ' )
```

Comment: Which RDBMS it is for? Date formats are RDBMS specific in general. Add the tag. It will also help you to attract the right people to answer.

Comment: This is SQL and openquery sybase

Comment: Sybase was a company, not a database.  Please specify which Sybase product/version you are referring to, as it may affect answers.  In this case if you are use Sybase ASE, CAST is not a valid function.  You will need to use `CONVERT` to do your datatype conversions.  http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug645.htm

Comment: I already figured it out thanks. how do I delete this thread?